# how to disable empty cells in datagridview clickable in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

This is my code so that every time the user clicks on a row it goes to a `textbox`, my problem is when I click an empty cell there is an error. How can I disable clickability of the empty cells?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{           
   txt_voterid.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   txt_fname.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   txt_lname.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   txt_age.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
   txt_vstatus.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
   txt_uname.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
   txt_pword.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: what is your datagridview template structure?

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions [link](http://imgur.com/a/nmLsy) like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line

```
txt_voterid.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

with this

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value)))
    txt_voterid.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```